# Datamapper TEXT limited to 65k characters by default — how to raise the limit?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sinatra, datamapper

I have a class that needs to have TEXT up to about 300k characters and it's stored in a PostgreSQL db.

Postgres itself has no problem with megabyte blobs, (eventually I will store them in S3), but Datamapper has a default limit of '65k characters' for a TEXT:

> By default, DataMapper supports the following primitive types:
>
> - TrueClass, Boolean
> - String
> - Text (limit of 65k characters by default)

I want to do something like

```
property :id,                     Serial
property :name,                   String, :index => true         
property :posted,                 DateTime
property :info,                   DataMapper::Types::Text, :lazy => false
property :data,                   DataMapper::Types::Text, :limit => 500000 # needs to be big is :limit correct?5
```

I know the lazy part is OK, because I got it from http://datamapper.rubyforge.org/dm-core/DataMapper/Property.html — but what is the keyword to use to override the limit on a TEXT field:

- `:length`?
- `:maximum`?
- `:limit`?

Or something else?

Comment: Maybe the default maximum is the maximum maximum; you can only lower the limit?  Try using `:length => 32768` and see whether that has an effect...

Comment: I first thought that :length did not work, but it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK,

Turns out :length does work.

```
class SomeClass
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,                     Serial
  property :name,                   String, :index => true         # strings are actively loaded 
  property :posted,                 DateTime
  property :info,                   Text, :lazy => false # This is short stuff a hundred or so bytes long that I want loaded 
  property :data,                   Text, :length => 500000 # Text is lazy loaded by default, but I also need to override the default length limit which is 65536 chars in DM
```

Comment: But does `:length => nil` work to get rid of the limit entirely?

Comment: `length: nil` does not work on DataMapper.  You get error `ArgumentError: +options[:length]+ should be Range or Integer, but was NilClass`. https://github.com/datamapper/dm-types/issues/29